# Convergence of a series if limit goes to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I am stuck on the following question. We are asked to prove the following:

Assume $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $a_n$ = L

1) prove that if L>1, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ ${1\over n^{a_n}}$ converges

2) if L=1 what happens in $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ ${1\over n^{a_n}}$

My attempt: 
1)I have a tentative proof, but I am unsure if i am allowed to assume that such an $n_0$ exists
  Proof: If $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ an<1 then there exists $n_0$ in the natural numbers such that there exists K such that 1$n_0$. Then let $b_n$=${1\over n^k}$, and $c_n$ = ${1\over n^{a_n}}$ As k>1, this is a convergent p-series, then as $b_n$ > $c_n$, by comparison tests the original series converges.

2) I am unsure of how to show this. I know that if L=1 the series diverges as it follows the pattern of the harmonic series. My one guess is to use the epsilon-N definition of a limit |$a_n$-1|

Any help would be great!

Comment: You've added LaTex on some equation, but not on all. You could try to fix that to make it more readable.

Comment: Also, if $\lim_{n\to1}a_n=L$, then this does not mean that the series diverges. If instead $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L>0$, then the series diverges.

Comment: whoops sorry, that was me copying from the latex, it should be infinity

Comment: Please correct your series. Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{a_n}}$? What you have written doesn't use a dummy index.

Comment: the sign for infinity is \infty

Comment: Wow you just changed the question completely...

Comment: I'm very sorry, I'm still trying to get used to latex and didn't notice my initial mistakes following the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, to get an N st $a_n>1$ for n>N, consider the definition of limit with $\epsilon=\frac{L-1}{2}$. Then do comparison with the smallest value $a_n$ with n>N

For 2, consider that by a similar construction to in part 1, we can do a comparison test with $\sum n^{-a_i}$ for useful $a_i$. Specifically, for all $\epsilon>0$, all but finitely many terms satisfy $a_i<1+\epsilon$. WLOG we can take $1<\ldots < a_i<a_{i-1} <\ldots <a_1 < a_0$. This gives us a new sequence, $b_i$, where $b_i=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-a_i}$. It should be clear that if this sequence diverges than the sum we are interested in diverges.

Can you think of how to show that this diverges? The way that comes to mind for me immediately uses the Riemann-Zeta function. If you don't know what that is, there's probably a lower level way that is eluding me right now. What kind of course is this for?

Comment: hm okay, so I can just assume that an=1 right away? The terms leading up to the limit don't really matter? It's been a while since i've dealt with limits odly enough

Comment: For 1 or 2?  For 1, you're given that the limit is greater than 1.

Comment: for 2, so you know the limit of an is 1, then can you just use comparison test or something? What's confusing me is that before it reaches its limit it can be anything, and it's only harmonic when =1 at its limit. 
Thank you so much for your help, your suggestion for 1 works perfectly! I'm just writing it out

Comment: Oh, I was thinking that you wanted just one example of a sequence so that the sum diverges, but it's true for any such sequence, so you probably are supposed to show that. Give me one sec and I'll edit a sketch into my answer

Comment: yes, that's what i believe! Would you have a suggestion as to how to go about that?

Comment: Posted the idea, though how you'd prove that the sequence I mention diverges would depend on the kind of course you're in. I'm sure there are low level ways to do it, even if they are not coming to me right away.

Comment: The course is the undergrad real analysis course, so we have not yet covered that. I'm a bit confused as to what the $a_i$ are.

Comment: You have your sequence $a_i\to 1$. Without loss of generality we can assume it is greater than 1, since if there were infinitely many terms less than 1, this question would be trivial by the p-test. We can also assume that it is monotonic decreasing (throw out the finitely many terms that are not).

I then used the sequence $a_i$ to make a new sequence $b_i$, which diverges iff the summation that 2 is asking about diverges.